# How to make a matrix by fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

I want to make a matrix using 'fscanf'. I already made a txt file, and opened it. But, i don't know why it doesn't work.

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE *filter;
  double coeffs[61];

  filter = fopen("coeffs_fir.txt", "r");

  if (filter == NULL) {
      puts("can't open it");
      return -1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <61; i++)   {
        fscanf(filter, "%e", &coeffs[i]);
        printf("%e ", coeffs[i]);
  }
  fclose(filter);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the reslult is -9.255963e+61 -9.255963e+61 -9.255963e+61 -9.255963e+61 -9.255963e+61 ..... and Press any key.

The txt file is array of exponential, like -9.460415e-18. 
-9.255963e+61 doesn't exist in my txt file.

Some people said use "%lf" instead of "%e", but it doesn't work.

Comment: probably usual \n problem. 1000s topics here**You have to check the `scanf` return value to know if the operation was successful**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct except the following: you are using `double` type, but your format strings for `fscanf` and `printf` expect `float` type. Many compilators would issue a warning like this:

```
test.c:17:24: warning: format '%e' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 3 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]
     fscanf(filter, "%e", &coeffs[i]);
```

So, just fix these two lines by adding `l` right after `%`:

```
fscanf(filter, "%le", &coeffs[i]);
printf("%le ", coeffs[i]);
```

Note: I did test the code above, it works (gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609).